# mac display-notification's icon

Tags: node.js, macos, osascript

I write in nodejs

```
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    var pwd = 'osascript -e \'display notification "'+path.basename(des)+'" with title "'+ name + time +'"\''
    exec(pwd, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    })
```

It comes likes
[image]

How could it be like
[image]

**Question :**

How can i change the icon display on left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's already an [answer for this on AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106904/change-the-icon-of-an-applescript-called-notification).

> As of the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/aslr_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW224) `display notification` does not have a parameter to change te icon.
>
> `display notification` will use the icon of your script. One of your option is to change the icon of your bundle (cf screen).
>
> [image]

Comment: Great. It would be nice if you accept the answer, so it'll be marked as closed. Thanks in advance.